# Função inverte números em array

Tags: c, array, funções

Como funciona essa função em c que inverte os numeros?

```
void inverte(int vetor[MAX], int n) {
  int i,aux;

  for (i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
    // troca posicao i por n-1-i
    aux = vetor[i];
    vetor[i] = vetor[n-1-i];
    vetor[n-1-i] = aux;
  }
  return;
}
```

Não to consigo entender.

Comment: Você consegue ler código, entende os recursos usados? O que você não está entendendo?

Comment: Na parte depois do for.

Comment: É difícil tentar explicar sem saber o que você não entende. Aí teria que dar uma aula, que não é o objetivo aqui.

Comment: Como poderia entender?

Comment: @bob explique a parte que você entende, ao menos, aí facilita pra comunidade dizer o que falta. Você sabe o que são variáveis, o que são índices? Sabe o que o `for` faz?

Comment: ali primeiro no for ele divide n/2; sendo que é um numero impar(vetor[5], n= 5 depois ele faz aquelas atribuições[n-1-i], eu não sei como ele consegue varrer todos os elementos do array.

Comment: @bob o `n` você é quem tem que fornecer, e tem que ser igual o tamanho do "array" pra função agir como esperado. Ele nao precisa varrer todos os elementos, só metade.

Comment: sim o n é 5, e o vetor é de tamanho 5, foi utilizado ali só para melhor compreensão.

Comment: os elementos já foram declarados. http://pastebin.com/TFfdzuTY

Comment: a função vai do 1o até o 2o item, e troca com o ultimo e o antepenultimo. Se varrer o array todo, quando chegar no ultimo vai estar "destrocando" ele, entao tem que parar antes do meio. O meio nao precisa mexer, pq já está no meio. Com 5 itens, bastam 2 ciclos. 1 -> trocar 1o com 5o, 2 -> trocar 2o com o 4o. Pronto, "array" invertido. Se fossem 6 ou 7 itens, bastaria fazer o mesmo com os 3 primeiros e os 3 ultimos itens.

Comment: vetor[0] = vetor[5-1-0]; é a mesma coisa que vetor[0] = vetor[4]. Da mesma forma, vetor[1] = vetor[5-1-1] é o mesmo que vetor[1] = vetor[3]. Quando `i` for o primeiro indice (zero),  `[n-1-i]` vai ser o ultimo (quatro), quando for o segundo (um), `[n-1-i]` vai ser o penultimo (tres). Independente do tamanho do "array", a logica é a mesma.

Comment: Acho que entendi. Obrigado @Bacco

Comment: @bob postei uma resposta, espero que ajude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vou pegar estes dados como exemplo:

```
vetor = 71,72,73,74,75,76,77
n     = 7 (que é o tamanho de "vetor")
```

Assim, o *loop* vai fazer com que `i` vá de `0` e pare quando chegar em `7/2`, que é `3` (como foi usado `i < n/2`, o `3` não será iterado).

Tomando por base isto, veja cada uma das iterações em ação, já trocando o `n` por `7`, em `[n-1-i]` e aplicando o `i` correspondente.

Estas instruções serão executada 3 vezes, com `i` valendo `0`, `1` e `2`:

```
aux = vetor[i]; vetor[i] = vetor[7-1-i]; vetor[7-1-i] = aux;
```

Vamos aplicar o loop, com o `i` e o `[7-1-i]` das 3 iterações nas operações:

```
i = 0 portanto 7-1-i = 6 -> aux = vetor[0]; vetor[0] = vetor[6]; vetor[6] = aux;
i = 1 portanto 7-1-i = 5 -> aux = vetor[1]; vetor[1] = vetor[5]; vetor[5] = aux;
i = 2 portanto 7-1-i = 4 -> aux = vetor[2]; vetor[2] = vetor[4]; vetor[4] = aux;
```

Vamos substituir o lado direito das atribuições pelos respectivos valores:

```
i = 0 portanto 7-1-i = 6 -> aux = 71; vetor[0] = 77; vetor[6] = 71;
i = 1 portanto 7-1-i = 5 -> aux = 72; vetor[1] = 76; vetor[5] = 72;
i = 2 portanto 7-1-i = 4 -> aux = 73; vetor[2] = 75; vetor[4] = 73;
```

Portanto, após a execução dos 3 passos do loop:

```
vetor[0] = 77
vetor[1] = 76
vetor[2] = 75
vetor[3] = 74 (isso nao mudou)
vetor[4] = 73
vetor[5] = 72
vetor[6] = 71
```

Comment: Entendi, é bem simples.